# Sometimes Email not sending on google app engine

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, gwt

I am working in a project with GWT, using Google App Engine email code for sending emails. Below is the code I am using to send email:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Inside Try Block");
    Properties props=new Properties();
    Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    Multipart multiPart=new MimeMultipart();

    // To Mail  Address
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myEmail));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(myEmail));

    // Email To to Multiple Recipients 
    InternetAddress[] mailToMultiple = new InternetAddress[toEmailIdArray.length];
    for( int i=0; i<toEmailIdArray.length; i++ ){
        mailToMultiple[i] = new InternetAddress(toEmailIdArray[i]);
    }
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,mailToMultiple );

    // Email CC to Multiple Recipients 
    InternetAddress[] ccmailToMultiple = new InternetAddress[ccEmailIdArray.length];
    for( int i=0; i<ccEmailIdArray.length; i++ ){
        ccmailToMultiple[i] = new InternetAddress(ccEmailIdArray[i]);
    }
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccmailToMultiple);
    //below line for add BCC if needed then uncomment 
    //message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(approverEmail));

    // Mail Subject
    message.setSubject(mailSub);
    message.setText(message1);

    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Ready To send Email");
    Transport.send(message);
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Email sent Successfully !!!!")

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using this code, sometimes email is not sent. Whenever email is not getting sent, I can see the log message `Ready To send Email`, but not the log message `Email sent Successfully !!!!`.

When the email is sent, I do get a log message; `Email sent Successfully !!!!`.
Normally I do get emails but sometimes emails are not sent.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: are you within the email sending quotas? Is your emailFrom address allowed?

Comment: yes i am. yes email from address allowed

Answer (score 0):

your `props` should `props.load(.properties FileInputStream);` or `props.put(key, value);`

like this

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(SendTextMail.class.getResource("/mail.properties").getPath()));
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);
```

or

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    prop.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);
```

Comment: djzhao thanks for response as a mentioned above code using Properties i am getting emails but sometimes i not getting email so using your above suggestion properties change will Email send everytime

Comment: @ djzhao prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost"); is this always localhost if i am deploying on server then shall i change its value? and what is the value for server?

Comment: yes, you need to change the localhost to your email server address.@Vijay Chougule